# Consolidating Duplicate Rows By Creating New Columns

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe, df.

| Player | Round | SC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dion Prestia | Round 1 | 118 |
| Dustin Martin | Round 1 | 126 |
| Trent Cotchin | Round 1 | 94 |
| Dion Prestia | Round 2 | 91 |
| Dustin Martin | Round 2 | 86 |
| Trent Cotchin | Round 2 | 84 |
| Dion Prestia | Round 3 | 86 |
| Dustin Martin | Round 3 | 90 |
| Trent Cotchin | Round 3 | 90 |

I want to consolidate the rows to look like shown below, but am not sure how to achieve it.

| Player | Round 1 | Round 2 | Round 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dion Prestia | 118 | 91 | 86 |
| Dustin Martin | 126 | 86 | 90 |
| Trent Cotchin | 94 | 84 | 90 |

I have tried using the following with no success:

```
reshape(df, idvar = "Player", timevar = "Round", direction = "wide")
```

as it combines into 2 columns, where column 2 is named 'SC.c("Round 1", "Round 2", "Round 3", "Round 4"' and all rows show a 'NA' value.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Round, values_from = SC)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Round,values_from = SC)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Player        `Round 1` `Round 2` `Round 3`
  <chr>             <int>     <int>     <int>
1 Dion Prestia        118        91        86
2 Dustin Martin       126        86        90
3 Trent Cotchin        94        84        90
```